# spark-submit doesn't read file from s3, just stucks on it

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-s3

I have an issue when I try to read data from s3 using spark-submit.
The app just stuck without any warning or console out when it reads the data from s3 bucket. However if I run the same application using python - it works! Maybe someone faced the same issue?

The code of test.py:

```py
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = """--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.711,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0
                                    --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
                                    --conf spark.driver.memory=2g --conf spark.executor.memory=8g
                                    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false  pyspark-shell"""

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(f"test").getOrCreate()
print("reading from s3") #stucks here
s3filepath = "s3a://path/to/file"
df = spark.read.csv(
            s3filepath,
            sep='|',
            header='false',
            nullValue='',
            inferSchema=True)
print("showing df")
df.show()
```

The spark-submit command:

```sh
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 /usr/bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode client \
--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.519,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0 \
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer \
--conf spark.driver.memory=2g \
--conf spark.executor.memory=8g \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
test.py
```

but when I use just `python3 test.py` it works and reads everything correctly without delay.

The spark version: 2.4.4

Hadoop version: 3.2.1

The file contains ~5K rows.

Comment: The issue was caused the spark resource allocation manager. Solved it by reducing of requested recourses. Why it worked using python3 test.py remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused the spark resource allocation manager. Solved it by reducing of requested recourses. Why it worked using python3 test.py remains a mystery